cline thinner when use with multirow and colortbl
When I use the \cline with the colortbl and multirow the cline will thinner than the other like red arrow cell (\cline{2-5}).

How to make it thick like the others line.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}}
    \hline
    \cellcolor{gray!10}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{gray!10}Title}\\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{gray!10}choice}&\cellcolor{gray!10}A&\cellcolor{gray!10}B&
    \cellcolor{gray!10}C&\cellcolor{gray!10}D\\
    \hline
    a&\(1\)&\(3\)&\(2\)&\(2\)\\
    b&\(2\)&\(3\)&\(1\)&\(1\)\\
    c&\(2\)&\(1\)&\(4\)&\(2\)\\
    d&\(2\)&\(4\)&\(1\)&\(1\)\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


the colortbl package documentation explains that \cline is not supported

In your example, I have loaded nicematrix and replaced the environment {tabular} by {NiceTabular} with the key color-inside (and also replaced \multicolumn{4}{c|} by \multicolumn{4}{c}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}|M{1cm}}[color-inside]
    \hline
    \cellcolor{gray!10}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor{gray!10}Title}\\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{gray!10}choice}&\cellcolor{gray!10}A&\cellcolor{gray!10}B&
    \cellcolor{gray!10}C&\cellcolor{gray!10}D\\
    \hline
    a&\(1\)&\(3\)&\(2\)&\(2\)\\
    b&\(2\)&\(3\)&\(1\)&\(1\)\\
    c&\(2\)&\(1\)&\(4\)&\(2\)\\
    d&\(2\)&\(4\)&\(1\)&\(1\)\\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}



You could use tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={c*4{Q[m,c,wd=1cm]}}, 
  vlines, 
  hline{1-3,Z}={solid},
  row{1,2}={gray!10},
  }
  \SetCell[r=2]{} choice&\SetCell[c=4]{} Title\\
  &A&B&C&D\\
  a&\(1\)&\(3\)&\(2\)&\(2\)\\
  b&\(2\)&\(3\)&\(1\)&\(1\)\\
  c&\(2\)&\(1\)&\(4\)&\(2\)\\
  d&\(2\)&\(4\)&\(1\)&\(1\)\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


